# displaying values from json to dropdown list

Tags: jquery, json

I have a josn data like this

```
{
  "VMs":[
    {
      "ID":"VM-WIN7-32",
      "OS":"Windows 7-32",
      "ADAPTER":[{"ID":"adap01", "name":"Linksys Wireless-G USB Network Adapter", "paths":"D:\\VirtualMachines\\Win7_X86_VM-001\\Win7_X86_VM-001.vmx","SNAPSHOT":"Wi-Fi-Test"}],
      "DUIConfig":[{"ID":"dui01", "name":"DGI","description":"dui description"}]    

    }, {
      "ID":"VM-WIN764",
      "OS":"Windows 7-64",
      "ADAPTER":[{"ID":"adap02", "name":"222Linksys Wireless-G USB Network Adapter", "paths":"E:\\VirtualMachines\\Win7_X86_VM-001\\Win7_X86_VM-001.vmx","SNAPSHOT":"Wi-Fi-Test"}],
      "DUIConfig":[{"ID":"dui02", "name":"2ddDGI","description":"2 dui description"}]   

    }
  ]

}
```

I have 3 dropdown lists .while selecting operating system `"Windows 7-32"` corresponding  `adapter` name and `DUIConfig` name should be load in the corresponding dropdon lists,
Am using following code.it is  working while selecting first `os` and not working while selecting second `os` from the drop down list  getting error

```
TypeError: data.VMs[i].ADAPTER[i] is undefined


...option value="' + data.VMs[i].ADAPTER[i].ID + '">' + data.VMs[i].ADAPTER[i].names.
```

code

```
$("#ops").change(function () {
    var adapter = "", dui="";
    var selected = $(this).val();
    $.getJSON('/json/data.json', function (data) {
      $.each(data.VMs, function (i) {
        if (data.VMs[i].ID === selected) {

          adapter += '<option value="' + data.VMs[i].ADAPTER[i].ID + '">' + data.VMs[i].ADAPTER[i].names + '</option>';  
          dui += '<option value="' + data.VMs[i].DUIConfig[i].ID + '">' + data.VMs[i].DUIConfig[i].names + '</option>';

        }
      });

      $('#adapter').html(adapter);
    $('#dui').html(dui);
    });
  });

  $.getJSON('/json/data.json', function (data) {
    var os = '<option value="">SELECT </option>';
    var adapter = '<option value="">SELECT </option>';
    $.each(data.VMs, function (i) {
      os += '<option value="' + data.VMs[i].ID + '">' + data.VMs[i].OS + '</option>';

      adapter += '<option value="' + data.VMs[i].ADAPTER[i].ID + '">' + data.VMs[i].ADAPTER[i].names + '</option>';
    });
    $('#ops').html(os);
    $('#adapter').html(adapter);
  });
}
```

htmlcode

```
 <tr>
            <td width="200px">
              Operating Systems : 
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
              <select id="ops" class="longcombo">
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td width="200px">
             Adapter :
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
              <select id="adapter" class="longcombo">
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
 <tr>
            <td width="200px">
             DUI Config :
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
              <select id="dui" class="longcombo">
              </select>
            </td> <td colspan="2" id="showdes">

            </td>
          </tr>
```

[jfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/t3PYQ/2/) but this code will load anything....

whats wrong with my code
'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `data.VMs[i].ADAPTER[0]` because the `ADAPTER` array has only one value, the same with `DUIConfig` also

```
adapter += '<option value="' + data.VMs[i].ADAPTER[0].ID + '">' + data.VMs[i].ADAPTER[0].names + '</option>';
```

Also you will get the current object as the second parameter to each handler, so no need to use index inside the each handler

```
$("#ops").change(function () {
    var adapter = [],
        dui = [];
    var selected = $(this).val();
    $.getJSON('/json/data.json', function (data) {
        //you will get the current VM as the second parameter, so no need to access it using index again
        $.each(data.VMs, function (i, vm) {
            if (vm.ID === selected) {

                adapter.push('<option value="' + vm.ADAPTER[0].ID + '">' + data.VMs[i].ADAPTER[0].names + '</option>');
                dui.push('<option value="' + vm.DUIConfig[0].ID + '">' + data.VMs[i].DUIConfig[0].names + '</option>');

            }
        });

        $('#adapter').html(adapter.join(''));
        $('#dui').html(dui.join(''));
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/VY7pJ/)

Comment: No same error is getting while selecting second os getting` data.VMs[i].ADAPTER[i] is undefined `

Comment: Now getting with this code......`adapter.push('<option value="' + vm.ADAPTER[0].ID + '">' + vm.ADAPTER[0].names + '</option>');
                dui.push('<option value="' + vm.DUIConfig[0].ID + '">' + vm.DUIConfig[0].names + '</option>');`
getting` data.VMs[i].ADAPTER[i] is undefined `

Comment: @Sush `data.VMs[i].ADAPTER[i].names` is again wrong.. it should be `vm.ADAPTER[0].name` - should not use `i` again and the key is `name` not `names`